# How to Run and Debug Odoo using PyCharm in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, debugging, configuration, odoo, pycharm

**Hello,**

**Question:**
How to **Run** or **Debug** odoo 8/9/10 using pycharm editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution of my question..

## Solution

**Step 1 :**
1
- First add the new project. i.e odoo 10.
2
- After add new folder in odoo 10. i.e conf
- After add the new .conf file in conf folder. i.e odoo_v10_base.conf
- odoo_v10_base.conf this file write configration for odoo10. i.e Right section give code.
3
- odoo-bin file is odoo 10 default file.
4
- Click on this Edit configration button to open pop-up.
[image]

**Step 2 :**
1
- Click on plus sign.
[image]

**Step 3 :**
1
- Now click on to Python from drop-down.
[image]

**Step 4 :**
1. Name : write any name i.e odoo_v10
2. Script : Give the path of odoo-bin file. (path : odoo10-->odoo-bin)
3. Script Parameter : First write -c and after give the full path of conf file.
    i.e -c /home/vmr/workspase/odoo_v10/conf/odoo_v10_base.conf
4. Click on apply button.
5. And after click on ok button.
[image]

**Step 5 :**
1. Click on run button.
2. Open this below section to show run odoo10.
3. odoo10 run this url like 0.0.0.0:8078 and this url write in browser to open odoo10.
[image]

Comment: If you use a virtual environment, you have to add it's Python Interpreter in the Settings, and then select this interpreter in the Step 4 menu

Comment: how to add the role "odoo" in the script execution?
This is my normal Run via Terminal: ``sudo -u odoo /odoo/odoo-server/odoo-bin --config=/etc/odoo-server.conf``

Comment: Still works, the url generated was not `0.0.0.0:8078` but `galaxy-a20.localdomain:8069` which still didn't work.  I had to use `http://localhost:8069/` which is generated if I were to trigger odoo-bin in terminal.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it using following method.

**Step 1 : Double click Shift key**.

When you click Shift key two times, open pop-up will open.

[image]

**Step 2 : In pop-up type key-map & select key-map option.**

[image]

**Step 3: Select Environment.**

After selection key-map new pop-up will open, from that you can select any environment.

[image]

You can select Environment Ex: Eclipse, after that you can debug & run same as eclipse.

This may help you.